# How to implement simple notification system?

Tags: jquery, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, notifications

For example I've the store catalog and the company catalog, and when I ordering goods in company, I wan't to send notification to director of this company(for example: the director of store [name] want to ordering 15 apples..), how can I do this? Can I create a table in db, like as:

```
CREATE TABLE `message` (
`Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`SenderId` int(11) NOT NULL,
`MessageContent` varchar(2000) COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL,
`MessageDate` datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
)
```

and in jquery do something this:

```
setInterval(function(){
   $.get('ajax_responder',dataObj,function(){
   // ajax callback
   // here is new notifications.
});
},5000);
```

or exist related ready systems?
I use Spring MVC, Hibernate, JSP, jQuery, Maven.

Thanks.

Comment: Like, send an email, or send a message to his web browser?

Comment: Send message to his browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Websocket support in Spring MVC to send messages from the server to the browser:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html

You can even send messages from the database to the browser if using Postgres:

http://blog.databasepatterns.com/2014/04/postgresql-nofify-websocket-spring-mvc.html